# Switch APN Android

Tags: java, android, settings, apn

Just wondering if anyone can help with the following question:

I'm looking for a way to change the default APN in Android. Basically if I haven’t received a message back from the server, I want to  change the way I access it by going via a different APN.

I've set all the APNS in the settings I'm just wondering if anyone knows a way to change the current connected APN?  Without prompting the users to select from the APN list in the settings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the answer for [this other question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867079/android-apn-enforcement/7869387#7869387

Comment: This should be probably asked on [android.se]. It does not look as a programming question, so you may not find the answer here (for more, read [faq]).