# "Ice Cream Sandwich" and WRITE_APN_SETTINGS

Tags: android, permissions, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, apn

Does anybody know how to write app for "`Ice Cream Sandwich`" using `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` permission ? `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` is now ignored in `ICS` and code touching APNs fails.

Comment: One of many similar links:  http://android.riteshsahu.com/apps/apn-backup-restore:  "Google seems to have changed the access level for applications which can write/change APN Settings in Android 4 (ICS). Now 3rd Party apps are not allowed to change APN Settings." Even requesting the permission “android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS” does not allow apps to write APN settings:

Comment: I am looking for java reflexion code which could workaround it. E.g. APNdroid works on ICS anyway. . .:-)

Comment: Why not look to see how they do it then: http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/

Comment: I got the same error as well. Where can we possibly raise this issue? Does APNdroid write apn settings on ICS with no problems at all?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Google high handedly decided to remove this. No dialogue comes up for confirmation, they simply make it fail. Thanks for acting like Apple! This ruins the user experience for users of non standard APNs (I'm on giffgaff which Google decided not to put on the official ICS list, once again, thanks). So I had to enter all the settings by hand. Think of all the users who simply wouldn't have a clue, this is insane.

You might like to make your feelings known to Google.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24227&can=1&q=WRITE_APN_SETTINGS&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29264&can=1&q=WRITE_APN_SETTINGS&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Answer (score 0):

Any of your favorite APN apps will work on ICS so long as you can set it as a system app. I use APN Manager Pro which is recognized by ICS as a 3rd party app, but after setting it up as a system app, I was able to write APN settings. Problem is in some cases MMS still will not work.

The key is to develop or install any APN editor as a system app.

Comment: This doesn't really help if your app is to be distributed to end-users.